# Elegantly summing named DataFrame columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am attempting to write a function that will sum a set of specified columns in a pandas DataFrame.

First, some background. The data each have a column with a name (e.g., "var") and a number next to that name in sequential order (e.g., "var1, var2"). I know I can sum, say, 5 columns together with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')
data['var_total'] = data.var1 + data.var2 + data.var3 + data.var4 + data.var5
```

However, this can be repetitive when you have var1-var30 to sum. I figured there must be some elegant solution to summing them more quickly, since the column names are predictable and uniform. Is there a function I can write or a built-in pandas function that will let me sum these more quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are writing out all the column names there a couple of ways to do the sum a bit more elegantly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
                   'var2': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
                   'var3': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)})

# Use the sum method:
df[['var1', 'var2', 'var3']].sum(axis='columns')

# Use eval
df.eval('var1 + var2 + var3')
```

Then you can always use the standard Python tools for manipulating strings to put together the list of column names:

```
cols = ['var' + str(n) for n in range(1, 3 + 1)]
cols
Out[9]: ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']

df[cols].sum(axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
data['var_total'] = data.filter(regex='var[0-9]+').sum(axis=1)
```

This will first filter your dataframe to retain only the columns that start with `var` and are followed by one or more numbers. Then it will sum across the resulting filtered DataFrame.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the `filter` method of `DataFrame`; you can pass it either a string or a regular expression, and it will just return the columns whose names match it. Then you can just call `sum` or whatever else you want on the resulting columns:

```
pd.DataFrame({'var1':[1], 'var2':[2],'othercol':['abc']})
  othercol  var1  var2
0      abc     1     2

pd.DataFrame({'var1':[1], 'var2':[2],'othercol':['abc']}).filter(like='var')
   var1  var2
0     1     2

pd.DataFrame({'var1':[1], 'var2':[2],'othercol':['abc']}).filter(like='var').sum(axis=1)

0    3
```

By the way note that I've called `sum(axis=1)` to return the row-wise sums, by default, `sum` will return the sum of the columns.